# Help with abbrevations

Tags: .net, vb6, abbreviation

I just read a work description with a lot of abbreviations that I did not recognize. Could you help me with these?

It's the words in bold I don't understand.

> .NET/Integration Architect in **VDA**
>   *Drive the implementation of the architecture review of the .NET GUI for **VDA**.
>   Manage the **WMQ** integration between .NET GUI and other core data systems.*
>
> .NET/Integration Architect in **BSI**
>
> NET Developer/Architect **UCHP**
>   *Development for Scanner and Printer applications within **UCHP**.*
>
> .NET Developer/Architect **TDI**
>
> VB6 developer **NASS**

Comment: Check out http://www.acronymfinder.com

Comment: All these .Netticisms, yet tagged VB6???

Comment: I didn't know if NASS had anything to do with VB6, so I tagged it as a precaution. But I'll remove it if it troubles you and you can't sleep =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WMQ: IBM WebSphere MQ](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=WMQ)

VDA, BSI, UCHP, TDI and NASS seem to be company names. Look them up in google and check whether any of the results make sense...